# How difficult is it for wild birds to find food?

Tags: zoology, ornithology

This question came to my mind when I was wondering if my parrots would have it better on the outside than with me. Also, is starvation a significant cause of death at different stages in a bird's life cycle? Obviously, this is an open ended question due to the many species and different habitats, but I wanted to know what the answer is in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you live in the Costa Rica rainforest then your parrot may be better off living outside in the jungle.If you live in downtown New York City then your parrot is better off living inside with you.Starvation , predation and accidents(especially in urban areas) are three main causes of early death in many species.